# crop picture as circle in PHP

Tags: php, crop

Is it possible to crop a profile picture as a circle? 
I tried PHP crop, but the quality was awful. Color shades changed and image quality suffered. Is there any PHP library which does this properly? Or some Apche program?

Comment: How comes you want to crop as a circle? Can you not just use border-radius: 50%; when displaying the image?

Comment: I wouldn't crop the actual image but use css to display it as a circle. Much easier, less destructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not crop image to circle. Image must be rectangular. The best solution is to use css with border-radius property - `border-radius: 50%`. But if you really need a circle you can try to add a frame using ImageMagic. One of possible solutions: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#badge_overlay

Comment: No need for the frame when css does exactly what they're after

Comment: @AndyHolmes you never know for what purposes he needs the image. Maybe he will not display it in browser.

Comment: It's to be used as a profile picture, so pretty sure it'll be displayed

Comment: @AndyHolmes Yet there is no harm in additionally providing an alternative solution.

Comment: No i know :) Just saying that it's probably easier for OP to use CSS for displaying rather than running additional PHP for a simple task

Comment: Thanks. I used ImageMagic. It's perfect plugin. Only one problem I needed to install to server.